# Getting quantity and unit

Tags: python, regex

I want to get bold parts in sentences below.

Examples:

SmellNice Coffee **450 gr**

Clean **2 k** Rice

LukaLuka **1,5lt** cold drink

Jumbo 7 gutgut eggs **12'li**

Espresso 5 Klasik **10 Ad**

Expression below works well until to the [last two](https://regexr.com/53odh).

```
\d+[.,]?\d*\s*[’']?\s*(gr|g|kg|k|adet|ad|lı|li|lu|lü|cc|cl|ml|lt|l|mm|cm|mt|m)
```

I have added `\s|$` end of the expression. Thinking that If the unit is not the last word then there should be a space after it. But it didn't work. Briefly, how can I capture all bold expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x2 = (
"\d+" #digit
"[,'\s]" #space comma apostrophe
"[\d*\s*]?" #opt digit or space
"((gr)|g|(kg)|k|(adet)|([Aa]d)|(lı)|(li)|(lu)|(lü)|(cc)|(cl)|(ml)|(lt)|l|(mm)|(cm)|(mt)|m)" #all the weights to look for
"(\s+|$)" #it's gotta be followed with a space, or with end of line.
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It works with brackets:

```
\d+[.,]?\d*\s*[’']?\s*(gr|g|kg|k|adet|ad|lı|li|lu|lü|cc|cl|ml|lt|l|mm|cm|mt|m)(\s+|$)
```